# Определить, какие значения столбца не входят во второй столбец

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, dataframe, анализ-данных

У меня есть DataFrame из двух стобцов.

Как мне автоматизированно проверить, какие из значений левого столбца есть в правом?

Чтобы было:

```
Элемент1 - False
Элемент2 - True
```

Были попытки создать цикл, но получилась ерунда полная.
Пытаюсь проверить перебором наличие всех элементов из первого столбца во втором столбце, но что-то не работает:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Motiv_sferi.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист4')
list = df['Столбец2']
for elem in df['Столбец1']:
    print(elem, elem in list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая функция `isin`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Столбец1': list(range(10)), 'Столбец2': list(range(5,15))})
df

    Столбец1    Столбец2
0   0   5
1   1   6
2   2   7
3   3   8
4   4   9
5   5   10
6   6   11
7   7   12
8   8   13
9   9   14

df['Столбец1'].isin(df['Столбец2'])

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: Столбец1, dtype: bool

df.loc[df['Столбец1'].isin(df['Столбец2']), 'Столбец1'].values

array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Вы, как обычно, спасаете! Спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант решения:

```
res = df.query("Столбец1 in Столбец2")["Столбец1"]
```